# On button click open link in IE extension(tab) in chrome browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have some functionality where i want to open particular link on **IE extension(tab) in chrome** browser. 
My application run on chrome browser but for this link i want to open in ie extension of chrome.
I have researched a lot but couldn't find anything constructive.
Is there any work around using javascript ?

Comment: You can add that URL in the options of IETab extension manually. Try asking IETab developers on their site if they have some way to configure links to open in IETab programmatically.

Comment: @wOxxOm But i can't force my application user's to manually do this that's why i am looking from code.So is there any way to fix from javascript?

Comment: @BHUVNESHKUMAR Most apps has special protocol, like `myapp://url-to.site`. Ask IETab developers if it's possible, then you can create special links

Comment: @Justinas i tried the same but it din't work - 
Here is code snippet this link is not opening neither in ie extension nor in ie browser
<a href="ie:https://www.google.com/">Google</a>